# HTML5 Video autoplay on iPhone

Tags: ios, html, video, webkit, autoplay

I have some kind of a strange problem. I try to create a website with a looped background video. The code looks like this one:

```html
<video src="video/bg.mp4" style="z-index: -1;object-fit: cover;" poster="video/bg.jpg" autobuffer autoplay loop muted></video>
```

This works perfectly fine on most browsers (IE struggles with this object-fit thing but I don't mind) but on iPhone the video won't autoplay but on iPad it does. I already read the [New  Policies for iOS](https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/) and I think I meet the requirements (otherwise iPad won't autoplay). I did some other testing:

- Removing overlaying divs won't fix it
- Removing z-index won't fix it
- Wifi or Cellular doesn't make a difference
- Video filesize doesn't make a difference, too

Am I doing it wrong or does iPhone simply won't autoplay videos and always requires interaction? I only care for iOS 10, I know that the requirements were different on iOS 9

Comment: You might be able to find some help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41360490/how-to-make-html-video-autoplay-on-phones-and-tablets/

Personally, I have yet to get any video at all to autoplay on an iphone, even after following all those tips and Apples policies.

Comment: It took me hours to figure out. To Try to save hours of everyone else I've summed up my findings in a blog. Hope it helps. 
https://medium.com/@BoltAssaults/autoplay-muted-html5-video-safari-ios-10-in-react-673ae50ba1f5

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39259418/html5-video-autoplay-doesnt-work-on-iphone

Answer (score 466):

Does `playsinline` attribute help?

Here's what I have:

```
<video autoplay loop muted playsinline class="video-background ">
  <source src="videos/intro-video3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

See the comment on `playsinline` here: https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/

Comment: `playsinline` worked for me in conjunction with `muted` keeping in mind the low power mode quirk on iPhone

Comment: `playsinline` Saved the day!!!! Thanks man.
BTW, new browser policies demand that if you want to autostart a video, start it muted or you won't be able to do it. +1 to @ken
Example for chrome:
[https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes]

Comment: If you're using React, note that the attribute `playsinline` must be written in camelCase: `playsInline`. Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Don't forget to add muted also with playsinline.
playsinline attribute won't work alone without muted attribute

Comment: Yes in React or Gatsby, you need to include both 'playsInline' and 'autoPlay' in camelCase.  This is a pro tip that will save you hours and trial and error.

Comment: In vanilla js, for me this doesn't work on iOS :( the video plays for a couple seconds and pauses - it doesn't even play the whole thing to stop before a loop... any ideas?

Comment: I used the “`video autoplay loop muted playsinline`” markup and the videos played in Safari for macOS but not in an actual iPhone. It seems that iOS currently does not support WebM format with VP9 codec, which is what we were using. After adding a second source tag with MP4/h264 video, the videos started working (and autoplaying) in iPhones, too.

Answer (score 133):

iOs 10+ allow video autoplay inline. but you have to turn off "Low power mode" on your iPhone.

Comment: great tip but i have a question about this that I submitted : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50400902/detect-if-ios11-device-is-in-low-power-mode-to-prevent-bad-ux-on-normally-correc

Comment: I spent the last hour or so trying to understand why my videos were not playing automatically. Thank you for this!

Comment: Thank you for this!

Comment: Its worth mentioning that we can't control the user's device and turn of Low Power Mode. The only thing we can do is prompt the user to "Turn off low power mode" to have a better experience

Comment: Happened to me as well and drove me crazy till I found your post. I was already looking at the specs of Safari 11 and 11.1 if they maybe completely disabled autoplay but it was only the low power mode... a devs life can be hard. :-)

Comment: This "low power mode" prevented me from going insane as to why my autoplay isn't working.

Answer (score 13):

Here is the little hack to overcome all the struggles you have for video autoplay in a website:

1. Check video is playing or not.
2. Trigger video play on event like body click or touch.

Note: Some browsers don't let videos to autoplay unless the user interacts with the device.

So scripts to check whether video is playing is:

```
Object.defineProperty(HTMLMediaElement.prototype, 'playing', {
get: function () {
    return !!(this.currentTime > 0 && !this.paused && !this.ended && this.readyState > 2);
}});
```

And then you can simply autoplay the video by attaching event listeners to the body:

```
$('body').on('click touchstart', function () {
        const videoElement = document.getElementById('home_video');
        if (videoElement.playing) {
            // video is already playing so do nothing
        }
        else {
            // video is not playing
            // so play video now
            videoElement.play();
        }
});
```

Note: `autoplay` attribute is very basic which needs to be added to the video tag already other than these scripts.

You can see the working example with code here at this link:

[How to autoplay video when the device is in low power mode / data saving mode / safari browser issue](https://shaktisinghcheema.com/how-to-autoplay-video-on-mobile-devices-on-low-power-mode/)

Comment: But it requires user interaction before the video plays? Since our video is in the stage of the page, we need to ensure that the video plays even if the user is on low-battery-mode and before he interacts with the page. Because it would be pointless to start a video once the user wants to scroll down.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem and I tried multiple solution. I solved it implementing 2 considerations.

1. Using `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` to embed the `<video>` code. For example:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `
    <video class="video-js" playsinline autoplay loop muted>
        <source src="../video_path.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>`}}
/>
```

2. Resizing the video weight. I noticed my iPhone **does not autoplay videos over 3 megabytes**. So I used an online compressor tool (https://www.mp4compress.com/) to go from 4mb to less than 500kb

Also, thanks to [@boltcoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5292808/boltcoder) for his guide: [Autoplay muted HTML5 video using React on mobile (Safari / iOS 10+)](https://medium.com/@BoltAssaults/autoplay-muted-html5-video-safari-ios-10-in-react-673ae50ba1f5)

Comment: Good to know, about the size requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, for late answer, but today i found that you need to turn off Battery saving on iPhone to make video autoplay.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem - the video not play on iOS. I tried all the code options "playsinline autoplay loop muted". The problem was the video I received was in the wrong mp4 codec. So what helped us, was to upload the video to Vimeo and download the HD Version again. The video is now playing on all mobile devices.

You could also try to use mpeg streamclip. Here is a screenclip of VLC - those are the correct settings. Hope someone does not have to spend 2 hours searching for the problem - happy holidays

[image: Codec we used]

Comment: playsinline worked for me. Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score -2):

Here is a simple solution to auto-play the video in IOS, I've already tried and it is perfectly working on IOS, Android, also on all the browsers on various platforms.

simply use (data-wf-ignore) and (data-object-fit) Attributes for the video and data-wf-ignore for the source tag..

You can see the working example with code here at this Snippet:

```html
<video id="myVideo" autoplay="" muted="" playsinline="" data-wf-ignore="true" data-object-fit="cover">
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" data-wf-ignore="true" />
</video>
```

Comment: data-wf-ignore is not a standard attribute - what does that refer to?