# How would I make video auto play in every browser?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need to play a video (auto playing) regardless of any browser or devices. Below code is working fine in Desktops (Chrome, Opera, Firefox and Safari); but, in mobile phones it is not loading in iPhone (showing controls) and in some android phones (not even controls)

I have tried adding attributes `autoplay` with `muted` and `playsinline`, also tried to force play with JavaScript.

Here is the HTML:

```html
<video autoplay playsinline loop muted poster="about-poster.png">
  <source
    src="about-video.mp4"
    type="video/mp4"
  />
  <p>
    Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video. You can find our
    logo video
    <a href="about-video.mp4">here</a> instead.
  </p>
</video>
```

This is the JavaScript code:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var media = document.querySelector("video");

  if (media.paused) {
    media.play();
  } else {
    media.play();
  }
});
```

I want to autoplay the video in every browser and every devices, and I could use some help.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Video autoplay on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43570460/html5-video-autoplay-on-iphone)

Comment: Just FYI, you can't. I have autoplay shut off in every single browser, on every device, I own. I personally find nothing more annoying than an autoplay video. Although the internet is filled with autoplay ads and so on, I never see them (and in fact see very few ads since I have adblockers on every browser/device I own). Other than that, the usual autoplay, or onLoad handlers, seem to be the method of choice. I've done a lot of ad work in the past and that's how we usually went about it.

Comment: It is generally only possible if you  have muted the video

Comment: Browsers are starting to automatically mute sound media also until user interaacts with it

Comment: I have tried `playsinline` attribute. This did not help. @TecBrat

Comment: @yunzen My video has no sound, also I have `muted` in HTML

Comment: Ok, that's why the flag text says "Possible..."

Answer (score 0):

`playsinline` attribute is missing

```css
video {
max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<video _ngcontent-c15="" autoplay loop muted playsinline preload="auto" poster="https://picsum.photos/360/240?image=990">
  <source _ngcontent-c15="" media="screen and (min-device-width: 721px)" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/96344/SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source _ngcontent-c15="" media="screen and (max-device-width: 720px)" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/96344/SampleVideo_720x480_1mb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source _ngcontent-c15="" media="screen and (max-device-width: 640px)" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/96344/SampleVideo_360x240_1mb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source _ngcontent-c15="" media="screen" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/96344/SampleVideo_360x240_1mb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: @DebadiptiPatra Where? I don't see it in your code.

Comment: I have already tried the with `playsinline` in my local. The problem is only happening with one android device I have (Oneplus One with android version 6.0) and iPhone 7(Chrome and Safari). All other devices playing fine.

Comment: @DebadiptiPatra Why isn't that information in your question?

Comment: Which browser in the Oneplus One smart phone?

Comment: iPhone 7 with Safari work with playsinline (tested on CrossBrwoserTesting with this codepen: https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/ROawbm)

Comment: I am using Chrome and Firefox (loading fine with autoplay) in my Oneplus One

Comment: playsinline is not helping. Still I am unable to autoplay in iPhone and my android phone. Can you check it [here](https://dev-pattem.github.io/video/)

Comment: I tested it with a codepen on crossbrowsertesting.com. iPhone 7 with Safari 11.4 and Nexus 6P (Android 6.0) on Chrome Mobile 72. Both worked! So there is something askew with your local hardware. Try deactivating all Plugins you might have

Comment: I haven't used any plugins, it is just a HTML file with a video. Can you please check this [link](https://dev-pattem.github.io/video/)