# How to hide video controls and enable autoplay in safari?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, safari

Suddenly iOS Safari forces controls became always shown, and that makes them unmanagable by controls attribute and also disables muted autoplay.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also ran into the same problem, and I found autoplay is disabled in "Low power mode"

> iOs 10+ allow video autoplay inline. but you have to turn off "Low power mode" on your iPhone.
> From: [HTML5 Video autoplay on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43570460/html5-video-autoplay-on-iphone)