# Video won't play on Safari & Chrome mobile even with muted autoplay

Tags: javascript, html, video, mobile-safari

I can't launch an autoplay video on a website on mobile, tapping won't work either.

```
<video width="270" height="533" id="video" autoplay muted loop>
  <source src="img/Mockup.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I also tried with

```
document.getElementById('video').load();
```

I have no clues how to fix it. Any tips ?

Thanks !

Comment: any errors in the console? "won't work" isn't much in the way of useful debugging info.

Comment: Nop no errors, by the way is there a way to inspect it with my phone ?

Comment: Yes. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging

Comment: Well, just figured it out. There was no problem on Android so I had to add playsinline and now it works fine !

Answer (score 5):

For anyone interested for Ios you have to add `playsinline` inside your video tag to make it works. See there : [HTML5 Video autoplay on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43570460/html5-video-autoplay-on-iphone)

Cheers !