# Force video to play on low power mode IOS - possible/workaround?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, video

So a feature of IOS low power mode is to **not play** a video (on iphones) when autoplay is present i.e.

```
<video id="video_1" class="video" autoplay="autoplay" loop muted playsinline poster="./assets/video/poster.jpg">
                    <source src="assets/video/echo-video-optomized2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    your browser does not support HTML5
                </video>
```

I am aware that you can use an event listener to detect this issue:

```
let header_video = document.getElementById('video_1');

header_video.addEventListener('suspend', () => {
    console.log('Device has suspened the video from playing')
    header_video.play()
})
```

I thought I could be sneaky and then this is detected just ask the video to play via:

```
header_video.play()
```

I've tested that the `.play()` and `.pause()` functions work on desktop but this does not work on Iphone - I suspect that the clever devs at apple have disabled these features while low power mode is on but (and here is the questions):

1: Is that the case? have the devs removed/prevented JS from using `.play() / .pause()` on low power mode for IOS deveices? (also is that universal for adriod as well?)

2: Can you force the video to play?

Thanks in advance for any help and feel free to ask any related questions -
Wally

Comment: What would be the point of disabling video auto play in low power mode if web sites could just force it to play anyway?

Comment: Hey @Paulw11, So So many different responses and open to a far larger debate on whether a software provider should be allowed alter a websites UI... But thats not the point - I assume its a blanket no based on your reply?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43570460/html5-video-autoplay-on-iphone