# Buildfire: Black screen on Apple Devices with live stream embed

Tags: ios, video-streaming, buildfire

Buildfire:
My app has several buttons built in wysiwyg text editor that is embedding live video streams.  People only go to the page when a live meeting is occurring.  On Android devices, the video starts playing instantly.  On Apple devices, a black screen appears fullscreen with no video.  If I minimize that black screen, the view is taken back to the page of the app with the embed.  That page shows the video playing which I can then make fullscreen to play fullscreen.  The issue is that the average user won't know to just minimize that black screen to get back to the page with the video.

Here are 2 ways that I have attempted to code the video embed's with no luck so far.

Any help is greatly appreciated

```
<p class="bf-wysiwyg-top"><video loop="loop" muted="" controls="controls" width="100%" height="auto">
<source src="linktovideostream" type="video/mp4" /></video></p>
```

```
<p class="bf-wysiwyg-top" style="text-align: center;"><iframe src="linktovideostream" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></p>
```

I have tried iframe embed and video embed to no avail.  The live stream link is NOT a youtube link, we stream to our streaming provider via rtmp.  The video embed link used above is https.

Answer (score 0):

This is more likely an issue with iOS not allowing your plugin to play a video when the page (your plugin) loads the first time and before the user has interacted with the page (your plugin).

You can have the video not autoplay or check other solutions here [HTML5 Video autoplay on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43570460/html5-video-autoplay-on-iphone)

Comment: Even if the video doesn't autoplay, the first time it loads it still prompts the black screen.  I have tried to also setup the stream link in the "webview" plugin and the issue occurs there also.

Comment: Once the "black" screen is closed and the live stream video is played a second time, it works fine.  it's the initial load that causes the issue.  I have tried countless variations of autoplay, muted, playsinline, no autoplay, etc.  The iframe with poster option wont play the video when the play button is clicked

Comment: Here is working demo video https://pluginserver.buildfire.com/temp/stackoverflow-RH2382.MP4

Comment: Snippet Used: <p class="bf-wysiwyg-top"><video autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls" width="100%" height="auto">
<source src="https://pluginserver.buildfire.com/temp/sample-15s.mp4" type="video/mp4" /></video></p>