# How to auto play Video on Mobile Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, html5-video

I want to show users a demo video of a feature.
I want to embed a 1MB mp4 video of about 15 seconds.

I tried the following code, which has both autoplay, muted, and JS play command, but it does not work. if I don't have "controls" I see just the first frame, and if I do have, it doesn't play automatically. I just want to have it play in the background, as if it was some gif animation.
Also, code is not responsive.

```
<div style="max-width: 640px; margin: 0 auto;">
  <div style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 0; padding-bottom: 56.25%;">
    <video id="vid" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;" loop autoplay muted controls>
      <source src="demo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
    document.getElementById('vid').play();
</script>
```

Comment: It seems that your question has already been discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43570460/html5-video-autoplay-on-iphone